# Oscilloscope type design with FPGA PL and PS framebuffer interface?

Tags: qt, embedded, fpga, xilinx, zynq

I am generating a certain signal (digital pulse) in one of my verilog module running on programmable logic in Xilinx Zynq chip. Signal is pretty fast, with clock of about 200MHz.
I also have a simple linux and framebuffer Qt interface running for later controlling my application.

How can I sample my signal in order to make oscilloscope like interface inside my Qt app? I want to be able to provide visual of the pulse I am generating.

What do I need to use to be able to sample enough data at such clock frequency? And how do I pass it with kernel module or mmap to Qt?

Answer (score 0):

You would do best to do what most oscilloscopes do: sample the data to RAM, and only then transfer it to the processor for display/analaysis, at a more "relaxed" pace.

On the FPGA side you will need a state machine that detects some sort of start or trigger condition, probably after a bit in a mode register is set from the software side to arm it.

The state machine will then fill samples into a buffer made of one or more block rams.  If you want to placing the trigger somewhere in the middle of the samples captured, you should it as a circular buffer, and have it record continuously, stopping configurable number of samples after the trigger, so that some desired number from before the trigger condition remain un-overwritten by newer ones following it.

Since FPGA block rams are typically dual port, you can simply hook the other port up to your CPU bus for readout.  You will probably want a register to read the state of the sampling state machine, and if you go with the circular buffer approach, the address where it stopped, so that you can unwrap the data to a linear record of time.

Trying to do streaming realtime sampling might be possible, but would be a lot harder and it is not clear that you could do anything meaningful with the data so produced in real time.  Still, if you want to try you would probably need to put a FIFO buffer in between the sampling and the processor bus, as you will probably only be able to consume data in chunks, while having to service other operations in between, so something is needed to absorb the constant-rate inflow of samples. Another approach could be to try to build a DMA engine which would write samples directly to external system ram, but that will likely be even harder.

You could also see if there are any high speed interfaces available in the CPU which you could leverage - they might be things originally intended for video, for example.

It also appears that you are measuring only a digital signal, ie, probalby one bit.  If you want to handle a higher input sample rate than the FPGA fabric can support, that could mean you could potentially use something like a deserializer block at the edge of the FPGA to turn the 1-bit input stream into a slower stream of wider samples to store.

In terms of output, once you have a vector of samples in a buffer it's pretty simple to turn that into a scope/logic analyzer type plot, with as much zooming, cursor annotation, automatic measurement or whatever you like.

Also don't forget that if the intent is only to use this during development, FPGAs and their tools often have the ability to build a logic analyzer right into the design, with the data claimed over the programming interface for plotting on a PC.